# Getting MobileVLCKit to work through Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, vlc

I've been struggling to get VLC working in my iOS app for a while now. Using Cocoapods, the MobileVLCKit is imported into my project. When I run the app now, it compiles with no problem. However, when I include anything from the MobileVLCKit (`MobileVLCKit.h`, `VLCMediaPlayer.h`), the app crashes, telling me that symbols aren't found. 
This is the crash:

```
Ld /Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSCamApp-cnnuesgeqommwvbqtarspgwsjgbn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Cameras.app/Cameras normal arm64
    cd /Users/JohnDoe/ios-cam-app/iOSCamApp
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk -L/Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSCamApp-cnnuesgeqommwvbqtarspgwsjgbn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -LLibraries -LLibraries/FFmpeg -LLibraries/kxmovie -LLibraries/MBProgressHUD -LLibraries/Nabto -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include -LLibraries/kxmovie/kxmovie.bundle -LLibraries/Nabto/include -LLibraries/Nabto/lib -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include/libavcodec -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include/libavdevice -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include/libavfilter -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include/libavformat -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include/libavutil -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include/libswresample -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include/libswscale -L/Users/JohnDoe/ios-cam-app/iOSCamApp/Libraries/FFmpeg -L/Users/JohnDoe/ios-cam-app/iOSCamApp/Libraries/Nabto/lib -F/Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSCamApp-cnnuesgeqommwvbqtarspgwsjgbn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -FFrameworks -F/Users/JohnDoe/ios-cam-app/iOSCamApp -filelist /Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSCamApp-cnnuesgeqommwvbqtarspgwsjgbn/Build/Intermediates/iOSCamApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/iOSCamApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Cameras.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -lPods-AFNetworking -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -lstdc++.6.0.9 -lc++ -liconv.2.4.0 -lbz2 -lz -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreAudio -framework Crashlytics -framework AudioToolbox -framework Accelerate -framework OpenGLES -lnabto_static_external -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework CFNetwork -framework AVFoundation -lavutil -lavfilter -lPods -lavdevice -lswscale -lnabto_client_api_static -framework Fabric -lavformat -lswresample -lavcodec -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSCamApp-cnnuesgeqommwvbqtarspgwsjgbn/Build/Intermediates/iOSCamApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/iOSCamApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Cameras_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSCamApp-cnnuesgeqommwvbqtarspgwsjgbn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Cameras.app/Cameras
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VLCMediaPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirstViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I installed VLC through cocoa pods, I got this warning:

```
The `iOSCamApp [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-iOSCamApp/Pods-iOSCamApp.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

When I add the `$(inherited)` flag and try to build, I get the following crash:

```
Ld /Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSCamApp-cnnuesgeqommwvbqtarspgwsjgbn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Cameras.app/Cameras normal arm64
    cd /Users/JohnDoe/ios-cam-app/iOSCamApp
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk -L/Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSCamApp-cnnuesgeqommwvbqtarspgwsjgbn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -LLibraries -LLibraries/FFmpeg -LLibraries/kxmovie -LLibraries/MBProgressHUD -LLibraries/Nabto -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include -LLibraries/kxmovie/kxmovie.bundle -LLibraries/Nabto/include -LLibraries/Nabto/lib -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include/libavcodec -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include/libavdevice -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include/libavfilter -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include/libavformat -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include/libavutil -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include/libswresample -LLibraries/FFmpeg/include/libswscale -L/Users/JohnDoe/ios-cam-app/iOSCamApp/Libraries/FFmpeg -L/Users/JohnDoe/ios-cam-app/iOSCamApp/Libraries/Nabto/lib -F/Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSCamApp-cnnuesgeqommwvbqtarspgwsjgbn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -FFrameworks -F/Users/JohnDoe/ios-cam-app/iOSCamApp -filelist /Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSCamApp-cnnuesgeqommwvbqtarspgwsjgbn/Build/Intermediates/iOSCamApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/iOSCamApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Cameras.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -lPods-AFNetworking -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -ObjC -lPods-AFNetworking -lbz2 -liconv -lstdc++ -lxml2 -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreText -framework MobileCoreServices -framework MobileVLCKit -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -lstdc++.6.0.9 -lc++ -liconv.2.4.0 -lbz2 -lz -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreAudio -framework Crashlytics -framework AudioToolbox -framework Accelerate -framework OpenGLES -lnabto_static_external -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework CFNetwork -framework AVFoundation -lavutil -lavfilter -lPods -lavdevice -lswscale -lnabto_client_api_static -framework Fabric -lavformat -lswresample -lavcodec -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSCamApp-cnnuesgeqommwvbqtarspgwsjgbn/Build/Intermediates/iOSCamApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/iOSCamApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Cameras_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSCamApp-cnnuesgeqommwvbqtarspgwsjgbn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Cameras.app/Cameras
ld: framework not found MobileVLCKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone know what to do? I've tried so many things and nothing seems to help. Autocomplete is able to read the VLC stuff and autocompletes it for me in Xcode, so the framework should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

That seems to be the problem. You're compiling for the simulator and apparently MobileVLCKit isn't compiled for it. `ld` is the linker that complains about this. Have you tried running it on the device?

Check what architectures your project and MobileVLCKit are active on.

Comment: When I build it for a device, I get the exact same message, except arm64 is changed into arm7 or whatever device I've tried to build it on.